# VSCode Python Test Discovery fails (June 2018)

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, pytest

as of today test discovery stopped working for me, it was tricky already to set up and I can't seem to fix it.

- VS Code version: June 2018 (version 1.25) (Insiders)
- Extension version (available under the Extensions sidebar): 2018.6.0
- OS and version: MacOS 10.13.3
- Python version (& distribution if applicable, e.g. Anaconda): 3.6.4
- Type of virtual environment used (N/A | venv | virtualenv | conda | ...): virtualenv
- Relevant/affected Python packages and their versions: pytest==3.2.1

Folder structure:

- src/ - All code
- tests/ - All tests
- .env/ - virtualenv
- .envFile -

(No __init__.py file in either src or tests)

Python Extension settings:

```
  "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "${workspaceRoot}/src"
  ],
  "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.envFile",
  "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.env/bin/python",
  "python.unitTest.pyTestArgs": [
    "-v", // increase verbosity
    "-l", // show locals in tracebacks
    "-x", // exit instantly on first error or failed test
    "--ff", // run all tests but run the last failures first
    "--color=yes" // color terminal output (yes/no/auto)
  ],
  "python.unitTest.pyTestEnabled": true,
  "python.unitTest.unittestArgs": [
    "*test*.py",
    "-p",
    "-s",
    "-v",
    "."
  ],
  "python.venvFolders": [
    ".env"
  ],
  "python.workspaceSymbols.exclusionPatterns": [
    "**/.env/",
    "**/site-packages/**",
    "_build"
  ],
```

`.envFile` = `PYTHONPATH=./src/`

Python Test Log when running "Discover all tests":

```
[1m============================= test session starts ==============================[0m
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.2.1, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: [redacted]/src, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.5.1
collected 0 items

[33m[1m========================= no tests ran in 0.05 seconds =========================[0m
```

And finally:

```
PYTHONPATH=./src py.test tests --collect-only
======================================================================================================================== test session starts ========================================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.2.1, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: [redacted, note no src], inifile:
plugins: cov-2.5.1
collected 225 items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered by Don Jayamanne himself in this Github Issue:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2047

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround for some folks:

My workaround when I ran into this was to look in the Python Test Log (see below), and notice an error about an ImportError. I fixed that import mistake and then tests were automatically discovered seconds later.

More info: To get to the Python Test Log, go to "Test" in left sidebar > Run all tests (icon has play button and two beakers), and when you run this, you should (hopefully) see two popup notifications:

1. Errors in discovering tests, continuing tests
2. There was an error in running the tests

Click on 'View Output' for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest downgrading Python extension to 2018.5.0. 
There are multiple issues on GitHub describing problems with running tests (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues).